# How to convert merge my logs with server name

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a log file above

```
m = '''Jan 23 2010 10:30:08AM - abc def Server-1 connected
Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM - abc def Server-2 connected
Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM - abc def Server-2 disconnected from server
Jan 23 2010 4:16:09PM - abc def Aws activity from 10.0.0.45
Jan 23 2010 9:43:44PM - abc def Server-1 disconnected from server
Feb 1 2010 12:40:28AM - abc def Server-1 connected
Feb 1 2010 1:21:52AM - abc def Aws activity from 192.168.123.4
Mar 29 2010 1:13:07PM - def def Server-1 disconnected from server'''
```

My expected out

`Server-1 - connected at 23/01/2016 10:30:08 and disconnected at 23/01/2016 21:43:44
Server-2 - connected at 23/01/2016 11:04:56 and disconnected at 23/01/2016 13:18:32
Aws - connected at 01/02/2016 12:40:28 and disconnected at 29/03/2016 13:13:07`

My approach and code convert the file into dictionary and format

Pseudo code

```
import re
x = re.findall(r'(.*) - abc def (Server-1|Server-2) (connected|disconnected)',m)
y = re.findall(r'Aws activity from (\d.+)', m)
for i in x:
    if i[2] == 'connected':
        print (f'{i[1]} - connected at {i[0]} ' )
    if i[2] == 'disconnected':
        print (f'{i[1]} - disconnected at {i[0]} ' )
```

Comment: `m` will be a string or it will be  a .txt file ?

Comment: You are converting the log into a list of lists, not a dictionary. Rather than building a list, which could be very large depending on the size of the log, use `finditer` instead of `findall`. Each iteration will return a match object and you can look at the various groups: `for match in re.finditer(r'(.*) - abc def (Server-1|Server-2) (connected|disconnected)',m): if match.group(3) == 'connected': etc.` Or at least read the file and match on a line by line basis.